# I am trying to analyze accelerometer data using the GGIR package but getting error attached below

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to analyze accelerometer data using the GGIR package. The file is available in location datadir.

The error is :

No files to analyze. Check that there are accelerometer files in the directory specified with argument data-dir

The code is :

```
GGIR(datadir="C:/Users/admin/Downloads/given", outputdir="C:/Users/admin/Downloads/out",f0=1,f1=1)
```

Comment: What does `list.files('C:/Users/admin/Downloads/given')` return, list? And potentially, do you have read/write permission there?

Comment: Yes i have read and write access for the location

Comment: What does `list.files('C:/Users/admin/Downloads/given')[1]` return? Humor me.